# jqGrid Navgrid button Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

The default jqGrid buttons (add, edit, delete, reload) are positioned on the bottom left of the grid. I would like them to be positioned on the bottom right. How do I get them to the right?

I'm using jqGrid version 4.4.4

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position: "right"` option of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters). If you use `viewrecords: true` option of jqGrid, then you should consider to use jqGrid option `recordpos: "left"` additionally.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. The position: "right" places it so far right that it's out of view. recordpos: "left" gets it on the right side of the pager in the middle of the grid. Is there anyway to get it all the way to the right?

Comment: @vmil: You should post more options, which **you use and to post the picture with your current results**. The demo could be helpful too. It can be that you need add some additional CSS rules to improve the results. Old version of jqGrid had design problem in navigator bar in case of many icons. I described the problem in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Redesign-of-the-structure-of-Navigator-Bar-of-the-pagers) and fixed the problem in free jqGrid (already in the version 4.8).